# links and buttons in iFrame opening windows in new tabs

Tags: .net, angular, angularjs, web-config, .net-4.5

I am working on iframing my old angularjs (Part of a .net framework 4.5.1 solution) screens in my newer angular 16 application and I have logic that sorts that out, but there seems to be an issue with links and buttons from within the iframe opening in new tabs.

How could I catch these and rewrite/redirect them to my iframing component on localhost:4200?

Would I need to edit the web.config of the old solution with some url rewriting/redirecting rule?

I would prefer not to code too much in the old solution. Any help is appreciated.